# Complexity of unbounded Gaussian convolution

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, matrices

What is the asymptotic complexity of doing a convolution of an unbounded Gaussian on an NxN input matrix $M$?

The naive approach is $O(n^4)$ ($R_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{l=1}^{n}M_{kl}*g(\sqrt{(k-i)^2 + (l-j)^2})$; $O(n^2)$ work on each of $O(n^2)$ elements); there is a fairly trivial lower bound of $O(n^2)$ (at least, assuming an arbitrary input and output matrix, at least one of which is explicitly represented).

I suspect the true asymptotic complexity here is far closer to $O(n^2)$ than $O(n^4)$; I am aware merely of the existence of methods of speeding up convolutions, but I am nowhere near familiar enough to know what said methods are or if they are applicable in this case.

Comment: In theory, an unbounded Gaussian has infinite support, so the complexity is also unbounded.

Comment: In practice, the decay is so fast that the values quickly become neglectable outside a disk and technically the complexity is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - assuming you are treating this as an infinite region, but only this finite NxN region having nonzero values, the complexity is _not_ unbounded, as you don't need to calculate anything outside said NxN region, fairly trivially.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - "the values quickly become neglectable outside a disk". That's decidedly not the case. Consider the case of an NxN matrix where only element (N,N) is nonzero. The value at (0,0) should be (very) small but nonzero, whereas if you approximate with a disk it will be zero. Your relative error is infinite in the disk approximation!

Comment: (Of course, you need to do something fancy like use a logarithmic representation in order to be able to actually handle this.)

Comment: You are right about the complexity.

Comment: "if you approximate with a disk it will be zero": I have no idea what you mean. In the case of a single nonzero (i.e. the impulse response), the result will be exact (to the float accuracy).

Comment: I covered this: (Of course, you need to do something fancy like use a logarithmic representation in order to be able to actually handle this.)

Answer (score 3):

Gaussian kernel is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter), which means you can do 1D-convolutions on every row, and then on every column. This already gives you $O(N^3)$ almost for free. If you do 1D-convolutions using FFT, then it'll be just $O(N^2 \log N)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) the time complexity can be reduced to $O(n^2 log^2n)$ see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164749/computational-complexity-of-convolution)

Comment: Sigh. Of course a computational complexity question is on Stack Overflow instead of Computer Science.

Comment: That answer is just a link and an assertion, and the link has been broken since 2013 (and isn't in the Wayback machine...)

Comment: Is this the lower bound, or simply an existence proof for an upper bound? I wonder if you can achieve e.g. $O(n^2 log(n))$ somehow.

Comment: There is a good [3b1b video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuXjwB4LzSA) explaining this, you can extend the result to 2D

Comment: I don't see how that gets $log^2(n)$. 2d FFT is $O(n*m*log(n*m))$, which for $m=n$ is $O(n^2 log(n^2))$, which is equivalent to $O(n^2 log(n))$. Please elaborate.

Comment: I think you might be confused by the notation $O(n^2log(n)log(n))$ = $O(n^2log^2n)$

Comment: Well, _don't use that notation_. $O((n\cdot\log n)^2)$ is much clearer. $\log^2n$ should, if anything, actually mean $\log(\log n)$, but that shouldn't be used either.

Comment: Given that the Gaussian kernel is separable, using FFTs the complexity is $O(n^d\log n)$ in any dimension $d$.